# Div class positioning

Tags: html, css

I'm having some trouble getting some elements on a page positioned correctly. As you can see in the image below, it does not look very nice. I'm trying to get  the text in the top-half of the page to position itself to the right of the image, to position the movie poster on top of (z-axis) the 'gradient overlay' so it does not gray out.

[image: a]

HTML (with swig):

```
{% if movie.imgUrl.length > 0 %}
<div class="topDivBanner" style="background-image:url({{movie.imgUrl}})">
{% else %}
<div class="topDivBanner" style="background-image:url('blank.png')">
{% endif %}
    <div class="bunnerOverlay">
        <h1>{{movie.title}}</h1>
        <h5>{{movie.year}}</h5>
        <p class="topDivText leftItem" id="movieLength">{{movie.runtime}} minutes</p>
        <p class="topDivText leftItem" id="movieMore">{{movie.genres}}</p>
        <p class="topDivText rightItem" id="movieYT">
            <a onclick="openLink('http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query={{movie.title}}+Trailer')">Trailer<i class="fa fa-youtube"></i></a>
        </p>
        <p class="topDivText rightItem" id="movieIMDB">
            <a onclick="openLink('http://www.imdb.com/title/{{movie.imdbId}}/')">
                IMDb: {{movie.imdbRating}}/10 ({{movie.imdbVotes}} votes)
            </a>
        </p>
        <div class="topDivDes">
            {{movie.plot}}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class "rlsTable" style="width: 90%">
    <table style="border-spacing:20px">
    {% for release in movie.release %}
     <tr>
        <td><a class="asimple" onclick="openLink('http://www.torrentleech.org{{release.detailsUrl}}')">{{release.rlsDetails}}</a></td>
        <td>{{release.size}}</td>
        <td><i class="fa fa-arrow-up" style="color:green"></i>{{release.seeders}}</td>
        <td><i class="fa fa-arrow-down" style="color:red"></i>{{release.leechers}}</td>
        <td><a class="asimple" onclick="play('{{release.torrentUrl}}')"><i class="fa fa-play-circle"></i>Stream</a></td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </table>
<div>
```

CSS:

```
.topDiv {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 700px;
    width: 1200px;
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: #EBEBEB;
    color: rgba(27, 27, 27, 0.98);
    overflow: auto;
}

.topDivFree {
    padding: 0px;
}

.topDivBanner {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top:0px;
    background-position: top left;
    height: 445px;
    margin-top: -10px;
    background-color: white;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}


.bunnerOverlay {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(27, 27, 27,.75);
    color:#EBEBEB;
    position: relative;
}

.topDivText {
    font-weight: normal;
    margin: 10px 30px;
    font-size: 17px;
    line-height: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    width: 300px;
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block!important;
}

.topDivDes {
    width: 90%;
    margin: 10px auto;
    padding-top: 10px;
    text-align: justify;
    position: relative;
}

.movieOverlayEx {
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    width: 90%;
    display: inline-block;
}

.showLeft {
    float:left;
    text-align: left;
}

.showRight {
    float:right;
    text-align: right;
}
```

Although it does not show in my code, the pop-up window with the movie details (which the HTML describes) has the `.topDiv` and `.topDivFree` style.

(Also, other design suggestions are appreciated).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try to work with the *float* property. In its simplest use, the *float* property can be use to wrap text around an image, i.e.

```
img{
 float: right;
 margin: 0 0 10px 10px;
}
```

Comment: Your solution (assuming you meant "img", not ".img") only works for an img element. @tsorn is using a background image instead. More work is needed for this answer to work for this question.

Comment: @Chrissi I put `float:left; margin:0px 0px 0px 300px;` on `.bunnerOverlay`, the div class that contains the text, and it worked.

Comment: tsorn, The fix is then coming from the margin you put on the class, not the float.  @aGer The particular problem wasn't fixed with your solution.  The original poster seems happy with your answer for some reason, but I don't think it answers the question.  It answers a generic problem of "How to wrap text around an image", which isn't what was asked.

Answer (score 0):

Put the text div inside gray one div. margin-left the grey div to adjust it so that it do not overlay the image. for center alignment use (display: "table") property to grey div and (display: "cell") property to text div. let me know if it works for you.